# FourierCosTransform bug?

Tags: bugs, fourier-analysis, integral-transforms

**Bug introduced in 13.0 or earlier and persisting through 13.2.0 or later.**

```
FourierCosTransform[Cos[(k + p) z], z, q]
```

gives correct result

```
Sqrt[\[Pi]/2] DiracDelta[k + p - q] + 
 Sqrt[\[Pi]/2] DiracDelta[k + p + q]
```

The same but with expanded argument

```
FourierCosTransform[Cos[k z + p z], z, q]
```

gives `0`. Bad surprise. Indeed, the situation is worse, because the difference remains even if we explicitly state that `k, p, q` are real numbers

```
In[]:= FourierCosTransform[Cos[(k + p) z], z, q, Assumptions -> {k, p, q} \[Element] Reals]

Out[]:=Sqrt[\[Pi]/2] DiracDelta[k + p - q] + Sqrt[\[Pi]/2] DiracDelta[k + p + q]

In[]:=FourierCosTransform[Cos[z k + p z], z, q, Assumptions -> {k, p, q} \[Element] Reals]

Out[]:=0
```

Comment: I can reproduce on `$Version == "13.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 3, 2021)"`

Comment: Strange, but these two commands  ``TrigExpand[Cos[k z + p z]]`` and ``TrigExpand[Cos[(k + p) z]]`` also give different results.

Comment: If you evaluate `p` and `k`, e.g. `p=3;` and `k=2-3*I;`, then both commands produce identical results.

Comment: @Rodion: As to your comment, *Mathematica*'s `TrigExpand` will only re-write the expression if the argument of the sinusoidal functions are in already expanded form.  This is, I imagine, a design choice, but I don't know the reason for it.

Comment: If you use `FourierTransform` instead of `FourierCosTransform` (which should yield the same result in this case, since the function is even), then both results are identical and equal to the result which is the sum of two delta functions.

Comment: I find the result of `FourierCosTransform[Cos[(k + p) z], z, q]` i.e. `Sqrt[\[Pi]/2] DiracDelta[k + p - q] + 
 Sqrt[\[Pi]/2] DiracDelta[k + p + q]` to be a bug, since `k`,`p`, and `q` are complex by default.

Comment: I believe this will return unevaluated in a future release.

Answer (score 1):

Let us go into deep. The function `Cos[(k + p) z]` depends on  `k` and `p` and `z` which are assumed complex by default. Claiming the correct result of `FourirCosTansform` to be `Sqrt[\[Pi]/2] DiracDelta[k + p - q] +  Sqrt[\[Pi]/2] DiracDelta[k + p + q]`, you silently assume that `k + p - q \[Element]] Reals` and `k + p + q \[Element]] Reals`. In other case this is meaningless.  If we deal with parameters, then the `Assumptions` and `GenerateConditions->True` options are useful. In fact, usual assumptions are `{k,p,q}\[Element]Reals`. Let us try it.

```
FourierCosTransform[Cos[(k + p) z], z, q, 
Assumptions -> {k, p, q} \[Element] Reals, GenerateConditions -> True]
```

> `Sqrt[\[Pi]/2] DiracDelta[k + p - q] +  Sqrt[\[Pi]/2] DiracDelta[k + p + q]`

```
FourierCosTransform[Cos[k z + p z], z, q, 
Assumptions -> {k, p, q} \[Element] Reals, 
GenerateConditions -> True]
```

returns the input. Of course, this is a weakness, but not a bug. Next,

```
FourierCosTransform[Cos[(k + p) z], z, q, GenerateConditions -> True]
```

> ConditionalExpression[0, Im[k + p] < 0]

If `Im[k + p] < 0`, then  (If I am not mistaken) the usual `FourierCosTransform` does not exist. Therefore, the above answer is of such kind "If $2+2=5$, then $2+3=6$".

Comment: Thank you but I donэt agree. This is a bug and it could be very drastic. First of all expression ``k z+ k p`` and ``(k + p) z`` are mathematically identical in all sense and assumptions. I understand that the result of the integration depends on the properties of the parameters, but this is totally wrong if result of ``FourierCosTransform[Cos[z k + p z], z, q, Assumptions -> {k, p, q} \[Element] Reals]`` is not the same ``FourierCosTransform[Cos[(k + p) z], z, q, Assumptions -> {k, p, q} \[Element] Reals]``. Otherwise it's a mess.

Comment: @RodionStepanov: The statement "but this is totally wrong if result of `FourierCosTransform[Cos[z k + p z], z, q, Assumptions -> {k, p, q} \[Element] Reals]` is not the same `FourierCosTransform[Cos[(k + p) z], z, q, Assumptions -> {k, p, q} \[Element] Reals]`" is your personal opinion.  The  returned input is  a weakness, not a bug.

Comment: I find the result of `FourierCosTransform[Cos[(k + p) z], z, q]` i.e. `Sqrt[\[Pi]/2] DiracDelta[k + p - q] + 
 Sqrt[\[Pi]/2] DiracDelta[k + p + q]` to be a bug.

Comment: What about `FourierCosTransform[Cos[z k + p z], z, q, Assumptions -> {k, p, q} \[Element] Reals]`` results in ``Sqrt[\[Pi]/2] DiracDelta[k + p - q] +   Sqrt[\[Pi]/2] DiracDelta[k + p + q]`` is it a bug for you?